Store Distinct String Values in a Variable in XSLT 1.0 and Use the Assigned Variable for Choose Statement
I'm mapping Oracle table output to an EDI file using Transformation XSLT 1.0.
I would like to get values from multiple lines but store them in a variable so I can use distinct values and show only the unique ones, then use it for the Choose statement. I'm having trouble with the variable for-each condition as it only outputs the first occurence or the line1 in the variable value output. I've given the desired output of the variable, if possible. If you guys have a better solution, that would be greatly appreciated.
Scenario 1    
    line1 column_a = IA    
    line2 column_a = R4    
    line3 column_a = ID    

Scenario 2    
    line1 column_a = IA    
    line2 column_a = IA    
    line3 column_a = IA


Scenario 3    
    line1 column_a = R4    
    line2 column_a = R4    
    line3 column_a = R4

Scenario 4    
    line1 column_a = ID    
    line2 column_a = ID    
    line3 column_a = ID 

`
<xsl:variable name="code855">
        <xsl:for-each select="/ns0:columnA">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- distinct somewhere here -->
    </xsl:variable>

`
Desired Output
Scenario 1    
    code855 = IA R4 ID

Scenario 2    
    code855 = IA

Scenario 3    
    code855 = R4

Scenario 4    
    code855 = ID




<xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$code855 = &quote;IA&quote; and $code855 = &quote;R4&quote; or $code855 = &quote;IA&quote; and $code855 = &quote;ID&quote;">
            <!-- do something here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$code855 = &quote;IA&quote;">
            <!-- do something here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$code855 = &quote;R4&quote;">
            <!-- do something here -->
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$code855 = &quote;ID&quote;">
            <!-- do something here -->
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

